# "As far as I can say", "as far as I know", "as far as I can tell"

Tags: word-meaning, as

As far as I am concerned.
As far as the economic problems here are concerned.
And
As far as I know.

My perception: All these are incorrect.  Because we just use " As far as I am concerned" to mean " In my opinion" . 
Therefore it does not actually make sense saying: " in the economic problems's opinion." " I can say my opinion" " I know my opinion" and so forth.

Comment: Note that we don't generally say "as far as I can say" but "as far as I can **tell**". Here "tell" has the sense "perceive".

Comment: The English language has many ambiguities such as this. Consider the difference between "near" and "far". Then consider that "as near as I can tell" and "as far as I can tell" mean the same thing.

Comment: @StoneyB: My first thought was using ***so*** instead of ***as*** in such constructions is equally "valid", but somehow ***as*** seems more "consistent" with usage in other constructions. This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=As+far+as+I+know%2CSo+far+as+I+know&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAs%20far%20as%20I%20know%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSo%20far%20as%20I%20know%3B%2Cc0) suggests BrE started to favour ***as*** about 1950, with AmE following about a decade later, but I don't know if that's a significant difference or not.

Comment: When I was a boy we were still taught that *so* should be used with negatives, *as* with positives: *Brian is as smart as David but not so smart as Mike." It's a "rule" I tend to follow just because it's second nature to me now, but one which is not reflected in ordinary use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are mistakenly generalizing on a single instance.

*As far as I am concerned* may be used in contexts where it has approximately the same effect as saying *in my opinion*; but it does not **mean** *in my opinion*.

Examine the actual construction of the expression *as far as X is concerned*:

> ***as far as*** means *to the extent or degree that*
>   ***X is concerned*** means *X is involved or relevant*

Consequently,  *as far as I am concerned* only has the effect of saying *in my opinion* ***when it is used to introduce an opinion***.

> **As far as I am concerned, Bob’s a jerk.** —*This means* “My concern in this matter does not go beyond recognizing that Bob’s a jerk; I am not interested in any subtler analysis of his behavior.”

But in other contexts *as far as X is concerned* takes on quite different meanings:

> **As far as the economic problems here are concerned ...** —*This means* “To the extent that our discourse involves the economic problems here [I have this to say] ...”

Similarly, *as far as I know* means *to the extent that my knowledge reaches*—that is, “I do not claim to know everything about this topic, but what I do know is this ...”

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context there are different words to replace the phrase “as far as”.

In your first example you can replace it with “regarding” or “concerning” or with another phrase “with regard to” or “with reference to”.

In your second example you can replace it with: “to my knowledge” or “to the best of my knowledge”.

Answer (score 1):

*As far as* shows **[up to the extent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20far%20as)** here in all. They all are possible. It's not necessary that you can **always** replace with *my opinion* and if you do, the context may change. Let me try one of the examples here...

> "He has an affair with her. Do you know that?" 
>   "As far as I know, he hasn't" - this **binds** your limitations of knowledge or information.

Now read this -

> "He has an affair with her. Do you know that?" 
>   "In my opinion, he hasn't - that's much of your opinion *not necessarily* dependent on news or information you get from your friends.

When we say *as far as*, we generally bind ourselves with some limitations.

Further examples will make it clear -

> My *remembrance* says that you never kept the keys in the drawer - you are quite sure about it 
>   *As far as my remembrance goes,* you never kept the keys in the drawer - means almost same but here, you are limiting your remembrance *a bit*.

Comment: +1 for binding the limitations of knowledge and information.